# The result wont show

Tags: php

This is my html file

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>


<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name"/>
<br />
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" />
<br />
<label>Department</label>
<input type="text" name="department" />
<br />
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" />

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file

```
<?php

echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo '<br />';
echo $_POST['email'];

?>
```

THe problem is everytime after i enter the name and the email. This 2 error will show:

**Notice: Undefined index: first_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lab6\process.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lab6\process.php on line 6**

Can anyone help me identify what is the problem actually?? Thanks. Btw i using xampp

Comment: you're using 2 files and you're doing `<form method="post" action="">`

Comment: How is the PHP file even being loaded?

Comment: Consider some `action=""`  :D

Comment: Now you might consider deleting this one, if it was just a careless mistake :)

Comment: @sjsam i didnt use the action i wanted to open it manually but the error keep pop out.

Comment: @ron this is why you have the error, because you open it mannually